# Problem deleting files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Happens sometimes but frequently enough to be a pain in the bum. I press Del or Shift + Del but the file stays there. Then when I try to delete it again, it says that I need permission from the Admin. For it to be deleted, usually I have to restart my computer

List of things I've tried:

- I have admin privileges
- Hasn't happened since I reinstalled Windows and another form of this happened in my install before the last one
- I tried `takeown` in `cmd` but it says `ERROR: Access is denied`
- The files sometimes disappear by themselves after 2 mins or so
- Refreshing the folder doesn't do anything
- Unlocker doesn't work either. It asks me if I want to delete it the next boot

Windows 7 x64 Pro

HDD:

- Fujitsu MHZ2320BH G2 ATA
- 320 GB
- 8MB Buffer
- 5400 RPM

Comment: What kind of file is it usually with? Video files? Update files?

Comment: @Synetech inc., usually any files or folders. Sometimes I make some temporary folder for stuff and I just delete it later and also, I'm learning programming and I build and compile a lot to see if they work and this problem is making that impossible because the built exes are locked and it can't be deleted or cleaned or recompiled

Comment: Are you remembering to exit the compiled EXE? I have had it happen to me that a compilation failed and I realized that oops, the last copy is still running.

Comment: Yes I always exit them. My compilations only fail when I make a mistake or if my compiler can't delete the files and recompile them

Comment: Without any specific errors or any specific cases, this is going to be impossible to solve.

Comment: Do you have any shell-extensions that would do any extra processing of files? For example, [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) is great because it gives some information on media files (go figure) in the status bar and/or tooltip, but to do so, it has to open the file and read some data. As a result, if you try to delete a file immediately after selecting it, the delete will fail because it’s still in use. Worse, if the file is corrupt, MediaInfo can spin in circles for a long time, trying to interpret the file, causing it to stay in use for some time.

Comment: I have Eraser, Avast, and Unlocker in the context menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think the problem was caused by either the hard drive or Unlocker. Not sure what which but I'm leaning towards the hard drive.

I did a clean install of Windows 7 with a real format not a quick one. Afterwards, I installed everything I needed but was too lazy to install Unlocker. Now my computer's faster, more responsive, and files disappear immediately after I delete them (Or shortly after if it's a big file) either by pressing Shift + Del or just Del.

There's also no problems with repeatedly building, compiling and cleaning my programs

Comment: +1 One of the shell extensions probably has caused weird Windows Explorer behavior, good that you found it.

Comment: Yep. I got rid of unlocker, and I haven't seen problems like this since, and it's been about half a year now

Comment: I don't really think these problems are related to Unlocker! I also had some deleting problems, but AFTER I installed Unlocker, I could at least identify the source of the file lockings - and possibly unlock these files. You could also have tried [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to try to identify the sources of the problems. As you said, you finally just reinstalled Windows, and your problems got solved - yes, a reinstall can solve many unexplored failures - but I don't think you should blame Unlocker so definitely,discouraging people from using it.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter This is old. And yes the problem was caused by unlocker. I know because I haven't had problems like this for almost a year now and I stopped using unlocker. Like Tom suggested, it was probably a glitch with Unlocker's shell ext. that caused explorer to act weird

Comment: @AlexYan: yes, I know it's an old topic, but I just found this question.:) When you had this problem, you didn't try to just uninstall Unlocker first (and possibly get rid of its remainders), and see if it solves the problem - you gave up, and simply reinstalled the whole operating system, which can solve a lot of problems by itself. This way I don't think it's proven that the source of problems was related to Unlocker, which I'm using without such bugs for a long time past. Other SWs could also confuse Windows - so not using it since and not having problems don't mean Unlocker was culpable.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter In the first install, I had the same problem, so I reinstalled to clear junk from old programs etc. Then I had the same problem, a few weeks later, I did another reinstall, and didn't install Unlocker. The problem was gone. I used Avast! free for both installs

Answer (score 1):

Try [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), it determines which processes still have the file open and allows you to gain access to it.

[image]

Comment: Unlocker doesn't work. It says failed and asks me if I want to delete it during the next boot

Comment: This might sound odd, but are you sure its not deleted, and thats why you are getting accessed is denied? i.e can you open the file?

Comment: No they aren't deleted. 'Cause sometimes they're still there when I restart and after that they delete normally

Answer (score 1):

For me it was only `.exe` files that couldn't get deleted. A quick Google search turned up this: [Can't delete EXE files in Vista / Windows 7](http://www.retrocopy.com/blog/28/cant-delete-exe-files-in-vista--windows-7-solved.aspx).

Re-enabling the Application Experience service solved this for me.